# How do I calculate support when having true posives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Somehow my evaluation of my binary classifier does not add up. This is the evaluation of my model:

```
True Positive(TP)  =  75 
False Positive(FP) =  64 
True Negative(TN)  =  47 
False Negative(FN) =  34 
Accuracy of the binary classification = 0.554545 
precision: [0.58024691 0.53956835] 
recall: [0.42342342 0.68807339] 
fscore: [0.48958333 0.60483871] 
support: [111 109]
```

Now so far it looks good, but I just realized that it doesn't really add up. As I see it support should return the total true values in each class. since I have only two, 75+47= 122 and not 111 for the true class. I understand that here TP and FN was summed up to get to 111 and TN and FP accordingly for 109. Or do I not understand support correctly? Here for the first class False Positives was added to True Negatives. That doesn't make sense, does it? How would I interpret this number?

So either I do not understand what support means, or maybe my code is wrong, but I looked at the documentation and made sure, that the values returned are assigned accordingly for the confusion matrix as well as precision_recall_fscore_support. So please explain what I am doing wrong here:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score  
def evaluation(y_test, y_pred):
     cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
     TN, FP, FN, TP = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()
     print('True Positive(TP)  = ', TP)
     print('False Positive(FP) = ', FP)
     print('True Negative(TN)  = ', TN)
     print('False Negative(FN) = ', FN)
     accuracy =  (TP+TN) /(TP+FP+TN+FN)
     print('Accuracy of the binary classification = {:0.6f}'.format(accuracy))
     precision, recall, fscore, support = score(y_test, y_pred)
     print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
     print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
     print('fscore: {}'.format(fscore))
     print('support: {}'.format(support))

evaluation(y_test, prediction > 0.5)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support is the number of cases you have for real positives and negatives. In your example there are 109 (75+34) real positive and 111 (64+47) real negative cases.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand: The number of positives is 139 (75 TP + 64 FP), and for negatives it is 81 (47TN  +34FN). In the 109 there are TP and FN added up. That does not make sense to me....

Comment: @LGR The number of *false* positives should not be included in the number of positives; The terms "positives" and "negatives" here refer to the real ones in the original data (regardless of the predictions). So, if we have 64 FPs, this means that these samples are in reality *negatives*, and, along with the 47 TNs (negatives that were correctly predicted) equal 111 real negative cases.

Comment: Oh man.... I think I get it now :D thanks for your help! Now I understand! False negatives are in reality also positives!